# Using Require.js in a Cordova HTML ons-page

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, requirejs

I am lost on how to use require.js within the HTML tag of an "ons-button" html tag item (*login.html*). I am able to use it successfully as long as I embed the code inside my require statement (*index.html*). Is there no way to use it directly in an html file that isn't html. I have tried using `<script src=""></script>` but then I do not know how to access the functions "*returned*" by require.js. Any help or direction would be great.

Background: I am pretty new to require.js. I have got it working somewhat, but still having a major problem. I have a login cordova app that is launched with *loginMain.html*, but I like to keep my code organized and in different files when possible. So the main page for this cordova app is *login.html*. I am trying to access functions store in *auth.js*.

The files are available in this zip:
http://www.filedropper.com/requirejsquestion



Code I believe is relevant:

loginMain.html (not working)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
<head>
    <!-- imports -->
    <script>
        ons.bootstrap();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="app.login" page="login.html">
    </ons-navigator> 

        <script type="text/javascript">
        require.config({    baseUrl: "js/"   });
        require(['auth'], function(auth)  {
            ons.ready(function() {});
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html (not working)

```
<ons-page>
     <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Log In</div>
        <div class="right"><ons-toolbar-button></ons-toolbar-button></div>
      </ons-toolbar>    
        <div class="login-form">
        <!-- other code -->
            <ons-button modifier="quiet" id="googleplus" onclick="auth.googleReq()">
                Sign in with Google
            </ons-button>
            <br>
        <!-- other code -->
      </div>

</ons-page>
```

I also tried this (*loginMain.html*) in the `<body></body>`

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var html = '<ons-navigator var="app.login" page="login.html"> \
        </ons-navigator> \';

        require.config({    baseUrl: "js/"   });
        require(['auth'], function(auth)  {
            document.write(html);
            ons.ready(function() {});
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

auth.js (believed to be correct)

```
define(function(require) {
    //initialize OAuth
    OAuth.initialize('MYKEY');

    return {
        //MORE FUNCTIONS
        googleReq: function()       {
            token = "none";

            OAuth.popup('google', {
                cache: true
            })
            .done(function(result) {
              //use result.access_token in your API request 
              //or use result.get|post|put|del|patch|me methods (see below)
              token = result.access_token;
              return token;

            })
            .fail(function (err) {
              //handle error with err
              return token;
            });
        }

        //MORE FUNCTIONS
    };
});
```